# Highlight comments of all the site authors

Tags: customization, comments, comment-form

On our WordPress page, we're several people who write articles. All these people are in different user roles. Some are editors, others are only authors and I'm the admin.

I know that you can highlight a comment or a reply of the posts author by writing

```
.commentlist .bypostauthor {
    # some styles
}
```

in your CSS file, but how could I alter this, so that every comment or reply written by a registered user of any of the following user roles author, editor and admin is highlighted?

Thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a filter called `comment_class` for that :

```
apply_filters( 'comment_class', $classes, $class, $comment->comment_ID, $comment, $post_id );
```

[Source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L506)

Just use the argument `comment` which is an object and you'll get `$comment->user_id` which could be useful to get user role and add your classes.

EDIT:

```
add_filter( 'comment_class', 'wpse_253517_comment_class', 10, 5 );
function wpse_253517_comment_class( $classes, $class, $comment_ID, $comment, $post_id  ) {

    if ( 0 === (int) $comment->user_id  ) {
        return $classes;
    }

     $user_data = get_userdata( $comment->user_id );
     $role      = reset( $user_data->roles );

    switch( $role ) {
        case 'subscriber':
            $classes[] = 'is-subscriber';
        break;

        // here would be other cases, other roles     

        default:
        return $classes;
    }

    return $classes;

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand how to use this. Would you be so kind to explain it?  :/

Comment: @Chwebo i've edited the answer